# Browser compliant rounded-corner navbar with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a browser-compatible navbar with rounded corners using DIVs and rounded images. I had it working perfectly in FireFox, only to discover that IE butchers it (of course).

The only problem I'm having now is getting my content DIV (navBody) to stretch to match the height of the side images. In both browsers now I have this:

http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/5088/40128898.jpg

```
<div class="navWrapper">
 <div class="navLeft"></div>
 <div class="navBody">
  <a href="/members">Login/Register</a>
 </div>
 <div class="navRight"></div>
</div>

.navRight
{
 float: left;
 width: 12px; 
 height: 25px; 
 background: url('/images/nav/tabright_off.png');
}

.navLeft
{
 float: left;
 width: 12px; 
 height: 25px; 
 margin-left: 3px;
 background: url('/images/nav/tableft_off.png');
}

.navBody
{
 float: left;
 background: #DDDDEE;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font: bold 12px Verdana, sans-serif;
 padding-top: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.navWrapper
{
 float: left; 
 height: 25px;
 display: inline;
}
```

I tried adding 5px padding-bottom to navBody, but this only works on FF and not IE due to  box model issues. Setting navBody to a fixed height (tabs should be 20px high) seems to do nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please supply the full code / demo?

Comment: I added the relevant CSS code

Comment: Do you really need rounded borders in IE? If not, just use the *border-radius rules. Remember, your site doesn't need to look the same in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

To the bottom of the `navBody` div and see if that helps things.

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't make a difference in either browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why adding a height of 20px in the CSS isn't working (on `navBody`), that would be my first guess. You could instead try making it `height: 25px` (to match the sides) but then change the `line-height` to push your text down (instead of the `padding-top`).

Another option (that would change the actual design of your nav) would be to set a `width` on all the nav items. Rendering engines in general prefer to have `width` set on any floated elements.

Comment: height: 20px works, but only in FireFox. The issue persists in IE - is any of the other CSS I'm using interfering with the height: property in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - FireFox was adding the padding-top (5px) to the 20px height I set to get a total of 25px; IE was not so the height stayed at 20px. Fixed it by making the height 25px by default and compensating in Firefox by cropping out the overflow in the wrapper div.